# GroupBy using date in EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I am working on an application where I am getting JSON results set from third-party API. I have deserialized it into my custom view model.

There is a list of records that contains records with repeating records I want to get the list with the average user on that date.

Here is my code and JSON. My point is to use the `dt_txt` date column in a single record and get the average temperature, wind speed, and humidity. It counts 2 from the below JSON to get the average of the above mentions fields.

```
public async Task<WeatherViewModel?> GetForecast(string param)
{
    var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WeatherReponseModel>(await httpClientApiService.GetRequestAsync(param, string.Format(WeatherEndPointsUrls.forecast, param)));

    if (response?.list == null)
        return null;

    // Here I want to rearrange the records. 
    // var orderList = response.list.GroupBy(x => Convert.ToDateTime(x.dt_txt)).ToList();
    
    return new WeatherViewModel();
}
```

Resulting JSON:

```
"message":0,
   "cnt":40,
   "list":[
      {
         "dt":1668632400,
         "main":{
            "temp":5.98,
            "feels_like":2.53,
            "temp_min":5.23,
            "temp_max":5.98,
            "pressure":1000,
            "sea_level":1000,
            "grnd_level":1002,
            "humidity":81,
            "temp_kf":0.75
         },
         "weather":[
            {
               "id":803,
               "main":"Clouds",
               "description":"broken clouds",
               "icon":"04n"
            }
         ],
         "clouds":{
            "all":83
         },
         "wind":{
            "speed":5.06,
            "deg":91,
            "gust":10.53
         },
         "visibility":10000,
         "pop":0.29,
         "sys":{
            "pod":"n"
         },
         "dt_txt":"2022-11-16 21:00:00"
      },
      {
         "dt":1668643200,
         "main":{
            "temp":4.69,
            "feels_like":0.63,
            "temp_min":3.86,
            "temp_max":4.69,
            "pressure":1003,
            "sea_level":1003,
            "grnd_level":1002,
            "humidity":78,
            "temp_kf":0.83
         },
         "weather":[
            {
               "id":803,
               "main":"Clouds",
               "description":"broken clouds",
               "icon":"04n"
            }
         ],
         "clouds":{
            "all":84
         },
         "wind":{
            "speed":5.69,
            "deg":94,
            "gust":12.3
         },
         "visibility":10000,
         "pop":0.27,
         "sys":{
            "pod":"n"
         },
         "dt_txt":"2022-11-17 00:00:00"
      },
      {
         "dt":1668654000,
         "main":{
            "temp":3.12,
            "feels_like":-1.59,
            "temp_min":3.12,
            "temp_max":3.12,
            "pressure":1006,
            "sea_level":1006,
            "grnd_level":1001,
            "humidity":73,
            "temp_kf":0
         },
         "weather":[
            {
               "id":804,
               "main":"Clouds",
               "description":"overcast clouds",
               "icon":"04n"
            }
         ],
         "clouds":{
            "all":97
         },
         "wind":{
            "speed":6.22,
            "deg":93,
            "gust":12.73
         },
         "visibility":10000,
         "pop":0,
         "sys":{
            "pod":"n"
         },
         "dt_txt":"2022-11-17 03:00:00"
      },
      {
         "dt":1668664800,
         "main":{
            "temp":3.11,
            "feels_like":-1.81,
            "temp_min":3.11,
            "temp_max":3.11,
            "pressure":1006,
            "sea_level":1006,
            "grnd_level":1000,
            "humidity":74,
            "temp_kf":0
         },
         "weather":[
            {
               "id":804,
               "main":"Clouds",
               "description":"overcast clouds",
               "icon":"04n"
            }
         ],
         "clouds":{
            "all":89
         },
         "wind":{
            "speed":6.72,
            "deg":100,
            "gust":12.45
         },
         "visibility":10000,
         "pop":0,
         "sys":{
            "pod":"n"
         },
         "dt_txt":"2022-11-17 06:00:00"
      },
      {
         "dt":1668675600,
         "main":{
            "temp":5.35,
            "feels_like":0.76,
            "temp_min":5.35,
            "temp_max":5.35,
            "pressure":1006,
            "sea_level":1006,
            "grnd_level":1000,
            "humidity":59,
            "temp_kf":0
         },
         "weather":[
            {
               "id":804,
               "main":"Clouds",
               "description":"overcast clouds",
               "icon":"04d"
            }
         ],
         "clouds":{
            "all":100
         },
         "wind":{
            "speed":7.59,
            "deg":111,
            "gust":12.21
         },
         "visibility":10000,
         "pop":0,
         "sys":{
            "pod":"d"
         },
         "dt_txt":"2022-11-17 09:00:00"
      },
      {
         "dt":1668686400,
         "main":{
            "temp":5.65,
            "feels_like":1.15,
            "temp_min":5.65,
            "temp_max":5.65,
            "pressure":1004,
            "sea_level":1004,
            "grnd_level":999,
            "humidity":66,
            "temp_kf":0
         },
         "weather":[
            {
               "id":804,
               "main":"Clouds",
               "description":"overcast clouds",
               "icon":"04d"
            }
         ],
         "clouds":{
            "all":100
         },
         "wind":{
            "speed":7.6,
            "deg":113,
            "gust":13.15
         },
         "visibility":10000,
         "pop":0,
         "sys":{
            "pod":"d"
         },
         "dt_txt":"2022-11-17 12:00:00"
      }
   ],
   "city":{
      "id":2950159,
      "name":"Berlin",
      "coord":{
         "lat":52.5244,
         "lon":13.4105
      },
      "country":"DE",
      "population":1000000,
      "timezone":3600,
      "sunrise":1668580182,
      "sunset":1668611564
   }
}
```

Model classes:

```
public class WeatherReponseModel
{
        public string? cod { get; set; }
        public dynamic? message { get; set; }
        public int cnt { get; set; }
        public List<ListViewModel>? list { get; set; }
        public CityViewModel? city { get; set; }
}

public class Main
{
        public double temp { get; set; }
        public double feels_like { get; set; }
        public double temp_min { get; set; }
        public double temp_max { get; set; }
        public int pressure { get; set; }
        public int sea_level { get; set; }
        public int grnd_level { get; set; }
        public int humidity { get; set; }
        public double temp_kf { get; set; }
}

public class CityViewModel
{
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string? name { get; set; }
        public Coord? coord { get; set; }
        public string? country { get; set; }
        public int population { get; set; }
        public int timezone { get; set; }
        public int sunrise { get; set; }
        public int sunset { get; set; }
}

public class Clouds
{
        public int all { get; set; }
}

public class Coord
{
        public double lat { get; set; }
        public double lon { get; set; }
}

public class ListViewModel
{
        public ListViewModel()
        {
            this.weather = new List<Weather>();
        }

        public int dt { get; set; }
        public Main main { get; set; }
        public List<Weather> weather { get; set; }
        public Clouds clouds { get; set; }
        public Wind wind { get; set; }
        public int visibility { get; set; }
        public double pop { get; set; }
        public Sys sys { get; set; }
        public DateTime dt_txt { get; set; }
        public Rain rain { get; set; }
        public Snow snow { get; set; }
}

public class Rain
{
        [JsonProperty("3h")]
        public double _3h { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
}

public class Snow
{
        [JsonProperty("3h")]
        public double _3h { get; set; }
}

public class Sys
{
        public string? pod { get; set; }
}

public class Weather
{
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string? main { get; set; }
        public string? description { get; set; }
        public string? icon { get; set; }
}

public class Wind
{
        public double speed { get; set; }
        public int deg { get; set; }
        public double gust { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the definition of your `WeatherReponseModel` class?

Comment: Is there something wrong with the code that you have? I mean, besides the `Convert.ToDateTime` being unnecessary because the `dt_txt` property is already a `DateTime` property. There's also the question of what an "average user" means in a data set without users...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a pretty straightforward answer, and I'm going to explain it below:

```cs
var result = response.list
    .GroupBy(listViewModelElement => DateOnly.FromDateTime(new DateTime(listViewModelElement.dt_txt)))
    .Select(dateGroup => new {
            dt = dateGroup.Key,
            TemperatureAverage = dateGroup.Average(x => x.main.temp),
            // not sure how "Wind" class looks, so replace "SPEED" with whatever the correct prop name is
            WindSpeedAverage = dateGroup.Average(x => x.wind.SPEED),
            HumidityAverage = dateGroup.Average(x => x.main.humidity),
    });
```

Note: not sure about the `new DateTime(listViewModelElement.dt_txt)` syntax, maybe you need to massage the string for it to work.

Note 2: Be aware of potential performance issues with this simplified approach. If your input (number of elements in `response.list`) is very large it's not the most optimal solution. If performance becomes a real concern more manual stuff has to be added instead of relying on `LINQ`.

So what does this code do?

First, as the question states, we're grouping the contents of the `respose.list` by DateTime constructed out of `dt_txt` property value, with time completely stripped. That's the     `.GroupBy(listViewModelElement => DateOnly.FromDateTime(new DateTime(listViewModelElement.dt_txt)))` piece. `DateOnly.FromDateTime` does the "remove the time bit" part.

This `GroupBy` creates a "group" of sorts. Think about it as key-value collection, one-to-many. In this case a "key" for each group is the `DateTime` value, and the "value" for each group is a collection (`IEnumerable`) of `ListViewModel`'s.

After that, for each resulting "group" (meaning for each distinct date in all `dt_txt` values here) we create a new anonymous object out of the results. That's the piece inside the `Select` lambda:

```cs
new {
            dt_datetime = dateGroup.Key,
            TemperatureAverage = dateGroup.Average(x => x.main.temp),
            WindSpeedAverage = dateGroup.Average(x => x.wind.SPEED),
            HumidityAverage = dateGroup.Average(x => x.main.humidity),
    }
```

You can see that `dt_datetime` is set to the `Key` prop value (which is present on the "grouping" created by the `GroupBy`), and other values are calculated from `dateGroup` values.

Final note: if you plan to reuse the values across your code alot I'd suggest creating a proper class to hold the results. Something like that:

```cs
class WeatherAveragesResult {
    public dt_datetime DateTime;
    public TemperatureAverage float;
    public WindSpeedAverage float;
    public HumidityAverage float;

    public WeatherAveragesResult(datdt_datetime DateTime, tempAvg float, windSpeedAvg float, humidityAvg float) { this.dt = date; ... }
}
```

And maybe creating a public method on `ListViewModel` class to remove the boilerplate `DateOnly.FromDateTime(new DateTime(listViewModelElement.dt_txt))`:

```cs
public class ListViewModel {
   // ...

   public DateTime GetDateValue() {
       return DateOnly.FromDateTime(new DateTime(this.dt_txt));
   }
   
   // ...
}
```

And do

```cs
var result = response.list
    .GroupBy(listViewModelElement => listViewModelElement.GetDateValue())
    .Select(dateGroup => new WeatherAveragesResult (
        dateGroup.Key,
        dateGroup.Average(x => x.main.temp),
        dateGroup.Average(x => x.wind.SPEED),
        dateGroup.Average(x => x.main.humidity))
    );
```

Comment: i guess OP wants to group by days, not buy dt (there are several dt points within the day, see `dt_text` prop in json)

Comment: *It counts 2 from the below JSON to get the average of the above mentions fields* - 6 data points within 2 days => 2 new average data points.

Comment: Fixed for `dt_txt` days.